# Github Package: Key not valid for use in specified state

Tags: nuget-package, github-package-registry

I am unable to use the package published by another user.
Process:

1. Added the new package name and source by updating the nuget.config
2. Added the package source username and password(APIKey)
3. Tried added the NuGet package generated by admin account though NuGet package manager but not able to see it.

Giving error:

Feeds used:

https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\

https://nuget.pkg.github.com/account/index.json

NuGet package restore finished.

Key not valid for use in specified state.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.